# Is there a way to post a session variable?

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables, sticky

I am looking to access a logged in user_id that is stored in the session, and post it in a query. So something like:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $_POST['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $ui = $_POST['user_id'];
} else {
    $errors[] = 'Please login before posting a book for sale.';
}
```

and then in the query:

```
if (empty($errors)) {
$q = 'INSERT INTO books (user_id, isbn, name, image, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'isssd', $ui, $isbn, $bn, $i, $p);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Now I already know that the first IF statement isn't correct, but I posted it like that so you PHP'ers can see what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to figure how to take the stored variable user_id, make it sticky, and then post it in the query. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to assign it to POST, and _then_ to another variable and use the latter? What are you trying to do exactly? Why not just bind the $_SESSION right ahead?

Comment: Essentially I am trying to just add the stored variable into the query, since in the db it is an indexed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have your variable stored in `$_SESSION['user_id']`..

Why don't you just use this:

```
$ui = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Comment: See. Something as simple as that. I am very grateful for your response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just put `session id` in a variable. no need to write any `POST` variable. 
You can use like this :

```
$your_variable = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//according to your code you can write it
$ui = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

And surely don't forget to use `session_start();` at top of your page.

Comment: You actually bring up something, inadvertently, interesting. I had the form included on the index page via include ('includes/form.php'). I had the session_start(); at the top of my index page, which requires the user to be logged in. When I submit the form in that format, what happens is the form.php doesn't or can't access the stored variables. When I duplicated it to form.php, it gave me an error saying I have started a session twice. Then I deleted the one on the index page, but then it can't access the stored variables on the index page. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: when you start a session in a form, then place it after form submission . otherwise your session will be clear every time when submit the form. 
And when you want to use the session variables in other pages then put `session_start()` top of those page.